# Jump into Android or learn Java basics first?

Tags: java, android

I am quite proficient in C and know some C++, but never touched Java. Recently I got an idea for an app which I think has potential, and I want to develop it.

I am planning to go Android first, cause it doesn't require a mac/iPhone.

So my question is: can I go straight to learning Android development, picking up the Java syntax as I go along and need it (after all I don't think it's much different from C/C++), or should I take a couple of weeks to learn the basics of Java first and then start with Android development?

Comment: Miyagi say: First learn walk, then learn fly daniel-san.

Comment: Check this and show me your big grin   http://oreilly.com/android/index.html

Comment: Short answer: Learn Java **first** before you jump into Android programming. It may seem simple enough for your basic `hello world` app but anything more complicated than that and you'll run into problems when debugging just because you're not aware of some of the quirks. I'll try to post a longer answer (pointing out a few of the rookie mistakes I come across on SO) when I get some time.

Comment: You want to get somewhat proficient in Java. So spend a few months learning OOP. Java is an object oriented language. So if you learn OOP, you'll quickly grasp java: Take the "Master Object Oriented Design" course on http://eliminatecodefear.com - One of the best resources for learning practical object oriented design and development with HW assignments

Answer (score 16):

Personally I suggest to study Java first so you won't spend a lot of time googling this and googling that. That will kill your productivity.

And if I'm allowed to suggest some books then I suggest [Head First Android Development](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920012825.do) and/or [Programming Android](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010364.do?green=23824853889&cmp=af-mybuy-0636920010364.IP).

On the other hand and since you are proficient in C and knowledgeable in C++, iOS development should really be easier to you to pick since Objective-C is a minimal programming language built on C.  But of course, it is your call.

Comment: Yeah I am considering iOS as well. I just didn't want to purchase a Mac, but I guess I could get a Mini to get going.

Comment: @daniels Yes indeed, Mac Minis are capable, fine and huggable machines.

Comment: In addition, by learning Java first you familiarize yourself with basics APIs you will use anyway in Android.

Comment: Is Head First Android actually available other than the online preview (which is reportedly a mess)?

Answer (score 11):

I think you should just jump right in. Java is similar enough to C++ that all you will have to get over is the syntax hump.  You should just get a good reference like the dietel how to program book and just go for it. You will learn what you need as you go along. Your programming experience will help you get up to speed quicker on creating your apps.

I would also suggest [The Busy Coder's Guide to Android](http://commonsware.com/Android/Android-1_0-CC.pdf) and the newly designed Android Developer Guide

The book is worth purchasing as the writer of the book is very active and can help you alot through your learning curve.

Hope this helps

Comment: `Java is similar enough to C++` What the ... Oh, you mean syntactically. No it's not, unless for loops are the apogee of your career.

Comment: "unless for loops are the apogee of your career". That is a good line :)

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox: Ironically, if loops are the apogee of a career then they are also likely the perigee of that career.

Comment: Isn't this `Busy Coder's Guide' somewhat dated? It's 4 years old

Comment: @YannisRizos : C++ has one form of writing for-loops, Java has two. So even a C++ person totally focused on using for-loops should assume they only know 50% of Java. :D

Comment: Well... C++ has more like 3 different forms of for-loops; range based, iterators, and the traditional form

Answer (score 3):

I would have a play around with Java for a few days just to see if you like it, then just jump right in no better way to learn than get your hands dirty.

Your programming background will help you. There's a lot of good tutorial sites that can ease you into android and java at the same time just try googling for them. Most of all ENJOY!

Comment: I'll add that you can probably get away with 1-2 days solid effort on this front or grabbing a book such as Head First Java (there's also a Java for C++ programmers title out there as I recall).  It's key to remember that Android != Java, you use a lot of the same syntax, but it's a different VM that runs the code, some things are allowed/restricted, others aren't etc

Answer (score 2):

> should I take a couple of weeks to learn the basics of Java first and then start with Android development?

Given that you target Android, it makes sense to simply pick their official tutorial of *Getting Started* kind and start studying it. If it is necessary / desirable to study Java along the way, you can expect this to be mentioned in this tutorial.

Per my recollection early versions of Android tutorials were of acceptable quality. I didn't work with it for quite a while though.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to a rather old thread, but just had to, since none of the answers or comments highlighted what I believe is a very important point i.e. "learning Object Oriented Programming (OOP)". Especially so, in the light of what OP wrote:-

> ... quite proficient in C and know some C++, but never touched Java...

That might indicate, that OP's Object Oriented Programming (and potentially Design) skills might need some propping up. At least, it did so in my case, and I'd have made a very similar statement.

I'd suggest learning what is called "Core Java", and becoming proficient and then, the switch to Android programming would seem much easier. The benefit of that approach is that Java forces OOP, in following ways --

- Clean (as in Puritan sense)
- Easy to grasp (as in simplicity)
- The only way (instead of having non-OOP alternative)

Also, "Core Java" can be learned pretty quickly for someone already fairly familiar with C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to jump straight to Android and to learn Java as I go. **Start is usually easy** - you can get Android Developer Tools from the Android developers site, where you will also find some tutorials to help you make the first steps.

However, without proper Java knowledge, Android development soon becomes overwhelming (at least it did for me). Luckily, there are tutorials for those, who want to learn **Java solely for Android development**. You can find them [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/search?button=&search%5Bkeywords%5D=learn+java+for+android+development&view=list) (they are designed for people who already know another language like C++/VisualBasic/etc.).

One way to check if you have enough knowledge to develop in Android is to sign up for an Android MOOC (like [this one](https://www.coursera.org/course/android%E2%80%8E)) and **check out the assignments**. The logic behind this approach is: Since Android development is what you really aim at, you can give it a go immediately. This way will help you realise what you can do and what you still need to learn. Plus you can always take some time out to brush up your Java skills.

Good luck picking the most effective for you way!